# Update Outlook Mail categories from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, categories, mailitem

I'm accessing Outlook via Excel because my enterprise Outlook VBA has been disabled. I'm specifically iterating though my Inbox and updating Mail.object categories property.

```
Dim objOutlook As Object
Set ObjOUtlook =CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim objNSpace As object
Set ObjNSpace = objNaspace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Dim myFolder As Object
Set myFolder= objNSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
Set myItems = myFolder.Items

For Each objItem In myFolder.items
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
set objMail = objItem

objMail.Categories = "Blue"
objMail.Save
```

This gives the Blue category in the picture but I want to be able update with the Orange Category formatting.

Can this be achieved through excel VBA?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have something strange going on here, you just change this line:

`objMail.Categories = "Blue"`

To

`objMail.Categories = "Orange Category"`

The name in the double quotes needs to be exactly the same as the one you have setup in Outlook - ie it's case sensitive.